# How to use created Django API Key to access API in browser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my django app I have created a url that could give Django REST framework API.The url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/

I have added API Key restrictions in `settings.py` so that only people who have API Key could access the API service.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIAccess",
    ]
}
```

Then in my Django Admin site I created an API Key as below.

[image]
Now I want use this API Key to access my API. But I don't know how to use it.
I tried to use some url in my browser like

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/?key=4278348c-2ff3-4f72-99e8-7284832d6049

But it still shows an error page as API Key is missing.
[image]

Does anyone know how can I access the API in browser? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried in an app like postman or with requests?

Comment: you need to use a header like `Authorization: Api-Key ********`

Comment: I tried postman, but still same results because I don't know how to add api-key in postman.

Comment: Could you please tell me where to write the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Django REST Framework's `TokenAuthentication` with your own method, and use that instead. Here's how:

**my_app/auth.py**

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class TokenAuthGet(TokenAuthentication):
    """
    Extends the class to support token as "key" in a GET Query Parameter.
    Supports standard method in header as a default.
    """
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.query_params.get("key", False)

        if token and "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" not in request.META:
            return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
        else:
            return super().authenticate(request)
```

Then in your setup:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'my_app.auth.TokenAuthGet',
    ],
}
```

Then you'll be able to pass the token as `?key=` like you give in your example URL. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. I added this code in to my file. It could work with the URL I given with `?key=`. but when I use the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events/ directly without add any token, it could still access the API. Could you please tell me how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Could that be because you are logged into the site via the admin or something like that? Trying to think of why that would happen.

Comment: No I did not log in. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I double checked against code I have in production, and `QUERY_PARAMS` has been changed to `query_params` - but I'm not sure that would have caused this issue. I've fixed it in the answer. Try it?

Comment: I have used the exactly the same code as you introduced. But the problem is the same, when I use url 127.0.0.1:8000/api/events directly the api could be accessed. I am not sure if I missed any thing here. Is the code you provided includes all the things need to modify? Thank you.